# Run processes with priority from shell (not “nice” )

Tags: linux, shell, command-line

I am looking for the equivalent command to `nice`, but for setting process priority and selecting the scheduler to use.

I need to be able to type (or include in a script) something like `run-with-scheduler batch a-big-long-command`, or `run-with-scheduler round-robin priority 10` to set the process priority and scheduler.

Everywhere I look there are article with titles “how to set a process priority in Linux” but they all write about niceness. As you may know niceness is not priority, and up until recently there was no way to set priority. However more recently there has been extra schedulers added to the Linux kernel. These other schedulers, allow priority, and have different behaviour.

E.g. the batch scheduler does not switch to often, and has lower priority than all other schedulers. This results in the tasks running faster (less switching), but only if there are no higher priority tasks running.

The kde tool ksysguard (graphical process viewer), has the ability to view and set a processes niceness, scheduler and priority. However, I am looking for the name of the command line tool.

**How, on the command-line, do I specify the scheduler and priority of a command?**

Comment: You don't get to set the priority. Only the scheduler does.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams that is for the normal scheduler, the one that has niceness. But there are now others: [Idle], Batch, Normal, [ISO], RealTime, FIFO. (the ones in [] are not in my kernel). Threads in RealTime and FIFO have a fixed priority, I think batch may have only one priority. http://oreilly.com/catalog/linuxkernel/chapter/ch10.html

Comment: I believe the `nice` command is the best you have available as a standard Linux utility. And for most purposes it should be quite sufficient. What do you need that `nice` doesn't do for you?

Comment: I know the recent kernels have support for multiple schedulers. I also know that the kde tool ksysguard (graphical process viewer), has the ability to view and set a processes niceness, scheduler and priority. I am just looking for the name of the command line tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `schedtool`.

Install package schedtool: ( on debian/ubuntu/mint etc.  run `sudo apt-get install schedtool` )

Then you will have a command `schedtool`, read the manual: `man schedtool`, and read up on the schedulers. Don't use the real time schedulers unless you really really know what you are doing. (you can't anyway unless run at elevated capabilities.)

Here are some examples.

- `schedtool -B -e long-process`
- `schedtool -R -p 1 read-time-process` #don't do it
- `schedtool -a 0 a-process-to-run-on-cpu-0-only`

see also http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/schedtool.8.html